# Any integer is less than or equal to 0

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, woocommerce, comparison

I have the following php `if` statement:

```
if ( 
    ( 
        ( 
            $order->get_total() >= $_POST["min-order"] && ( 
                isset($_POST["min-order"]) 
                && !empty($_POST["min-order"]) 
            ) 
        ) || empty($_POST["min-order"]) 
    ) && ( 
        ( 
            $order->get_total() <= $_POST["max-order"] && ( 
                isset($_POST["max-order"]) 
                && !empty($_POST["max-order"]) 
            ) 
        ) || empty($_POST["max-order"]) 
    ) 
) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Somehow if `max-order` is set to `0`, any number is less than or equal to 0. What am I missing here?

Comment: your line is unreadable. Please make it more clear by formatting it

Comment: `empty($_POST["max-order"])` That will evaluate to `true`, even if it's set to `0`...

Comment: @Machavity, what would be a good way to check for something is actually empty?

Comment: @Tristan.L Depends a great deal on when the values are passed and what is passed. Are you actually passing it as empty, or are you using this as a poor man's `isset`?

Comment: array_key_exists($_POST["max-order"]) is a safer way to check if something was passed or not

Comment: @Machavity `max-order` should contain an int. The check should validate if the `max-order` is either left empty or if the order total is less than or equal to the int in `max-order`.